# Merge PDFs from python list of WindowsPath paths

Tags: python, pdf

I have an excel file with some data in rows and columns and I am targetting at take the file names from each row and merge those into one pdf file (simply each row to one pdf file)
This is an example of a list `['1', '112238', '112239', '112240', '112337', '112338']` the first element in the python list will be the pdf name and the other elements are the file names that is supposed to be existing in directory named `Files`
Here's my attempt till now

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

BASE_DIR = Path.cwd()
MAIN_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'Files'
FINAL_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'Final'

try:
    shutil.rmtree(FINAL_DIR)
except:
    pass
FINAL_DIR.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)


df = pd.read_excel('MainFile.xlsx', dtype = str)

for l in df.T.columns:
    new_list = list(df.T[l][df.T[l].notna()])
    files_list = [MAIN_DIR / f'{i}.pdf' for i in new_list[1:]]

    final_list = []
    final_list.append(new_list[0])

    for file in files_list:
        if file.exists():
            final_list.append(file)
        else:
            print(f'{file} ---> NOT Exists')

    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for pdf in final_list[1:]:
        merger.append(pdf)

    merger.write(FINAL_DIR / f'{final_list[0]}.pdf')
    merger.close()
```

Here's a snapshot of the excel file that I read the file names from

[image]

and the pdf files in directory named `Files`

When I tried to run the script, I encountered an error like that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\demo.py", line 33, in <module>
    merger.append(pdf)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 203, in append
    self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, bookmark, pages, import_bookmarks)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 133, in merge
    pdfr = PdfFileReader(fileobj, strict=self.strict)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1084, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1689, in read
    stream.seek(-1, 2)
AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

I have tried this modification `merger.append(str(Path(pdf)))` and it seems to skip the first problem (I am not sure) but now I got another error

```
PdfReadWarning: Xref table not zero-indexed. ID numbers for objects will be corrected. [pdf.py:1736]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\demo.py", line 39, in <module>
    merger.write(FINAL_DIR / f'{str(final_list[0])}.pdf')
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 230, in write
    self.output.write(fileobj)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 487, in write
    stream.write(self._header + b_("\n"))
AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by these two modifications

```
merger.append(str(Path(pdf)))
```

and I used os to join the path as I failed to use Path

```
merger.write(os.path.join(str(FINAL_DIR), str(final_list[0] + '.pdf')))
```